# Sum and convert time to sec in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, date-manipulation

I have the time value in one column like below.
Now I need to sum this column and convert the result to minutes.

[image: My data]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the time to seconds and then divide by 60 to get minutes.  Something like:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`activeTime`))/60 FROM tableName
```

That will give you the decimal version of the minutes (e.g. 5.8 minutes = 5 minutes and 48 seconds). If you want the minutes in time notation (e.g. 05:48):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`activeTime`)) ) FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help you:

Convert time into seconds,in your case column name is activeTime:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('00:12:0');
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(your_column);
```

Perform sum operation:

```
 SELECT SUM(output_of_TIME_TO_SEC) AS "total second" FROM table_name;
```